# Prove/Disprove: $S$ not invertible and $\dim(\ker(T)+\dim(\ker(S)\geq\dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite vector space and $S,T:V\to V$ linear transformations S.T $T\circ S=0$
>
> Prove/Disprove:
>
> 1.if $T\neq 0$ then $S$ is not invertible
>
> 2. $\dim(\ker(T)+\dim(\ker(S)\geq\dim(V)$

1. Let assume that $S$ is invertible so there is $S^{-1}$ such that

$$T\circ S\circ S^{-1}=0\iff T=0$$ contradiction

2. seems wrong but I can not find an example

Comment: You can't find because it is true. You have four important objects in V: ker S , ker T , im S, im T. Can you rephrase TS= 0 in terms of them? Second question: how their dimension are linked?

Comment: @AndreaMarino nope :( still trying

Comment: I will tell you: TS =0 means Im S is contained in ker T. Why? Furthermore, remember that the sum of the dimensions of ker and Im of a linear application is the dimension of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $TS=0$ implies that 
$$
\dim(\ker(TS))=\dim(V)
$$
Can you convince yourself that $\dim(\ker(TS))\leq \dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\ker(S))$?

Comment: because $dim(ker(S))\leq dim(Ker(T))$?

Comment: @gbox that need not be true, we know nothing about $T$ and $S$.

Comment: $v\in ker(S)$ so $S(v)=0$ then $T(S(v))=0$ does not $ker(S)\subseteq ker(T)$?

Comment: That tells you nothing about T, it’s a linear map, of course it sends zero to zero . Try the same type of analysis on TS